# Citations rendered as 'Bloggs et al. (1999,1999)', not 'Bloggs et al. (1999a,b)'

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have two multi-author references that have the same senior author, but differ in the junior authors; BibTeX renders this citation in the text as 'Bloggs et al. (1999,1999)'. It should of course display 'Bloggs et al. (1999a,b)'.

How can I force it to append letter suffixes to the date when I have multiple 'Bloggs et. al.' references published in the same year?

Comment: Without a MWE, this question is going to be 'too localized' as we can't hope to solve it without some idea of your input.

Comment: I will close the question now. Feel free to edit the question to make it clearer, we could reopen it then.